# Drupal 8 cannot add JS to library subtheme

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

First time with Drupal. This should be easy. I need to add in some JS files to my sub theme globally. Cache is cleared every time when testing. 
I am building off the default bootstrap theme.

Error: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

SUBTHEME.libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}

global-scripting:
    js:
        js/global.js: {}
```

SUBTHEME.info.yml

```
libraries:

      - 'SUBTHEME/global-styling'
      - 'SUBTHEME/global-scripting'
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to just add a js file

dont change

```
libraries:
 - 'hytorc/global-styling'

global-styling:


css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
      js/global.js: {}
```